# SVF2 Public Beta - Models are not translated to SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

i just tried the [SVF2 public beta](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format).
I tried the translation on four models, but none of them worked. They are still in svf format and my cloud credits have been deducted.

As explained in the documentation, i just changed the output.formats.type to "svf2".

```
 const job = {
    input,
    output: {
      //force: true,
      formats: [
        {
          views: ["2d", "3d"],
          type: "svf2",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

I am using node.js sdk version:

> "forge-apis": "^0.7.3",

Viewer Version 7.29 with the init options:

```
 const viewerEnv = await this.initialize({
      // useConsolidation: true,
      // env: dbModel.env,
      // edgeRendering: true,
      // lightPreset: "Boardwalk",
      // envMapBackground: true,
      // getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
      //   onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds)
      // }
   env: "MD20ProdUS",
   api: "D3S",
 });
```

I checked the output-format with:
[image]

For all four translations, the translation-progress callback stopped between 90-98%. I never reached the 100% callback, but all models are translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have not updated the node.js SDK yet for SVF2, so I suspect even with those changes, it may be reverting to SVF.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. A little tip for next time:
it would be nice to hear something like that in the announcements.

Comment: The npm version was updated to 0.8.3 to support svf2-format. 
But it is still not working for me. The output is still in SVF Format.